# Yii2 Color Picker in Form

Tags: forms, colors, yii2, color-picker

Is there any built in class or an extinction that makes the user pick  color from something like this?

[image: Colour Picker]

Comment: you can also use `cliff363825/yii2-colorpicker` at https://github.com/cliff363825/yii2-colorpicker

Answer (score 5):

You can simply render a color input like this with out using any plugins.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'color', [
    'template' => "{input}"
    ])->input('color',['class'=>"input_class"]) ?>
```

Comment: HTML5 color input is not compatible with some browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `kartik\widgets\ColorInput` widget. first install `kartik\widgets\ColorInput` from this [link](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput)

e.g. (**Updated**)

```
use kartik\widgets\ColorInput; or kartik\color\ColorInput;(for previous ver.)

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form',
]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'color_code')->widget(ColorInput::classname(), ['options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Color...'],]); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary btn-create' : 'btn btn-info btn-create']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: I understand how it should work. I installed the kartik\color\ColorInput with composer, but the app doesn't see it. The error says: "Class 'kartik\color\ColorInput' not found" - Any ideas? @gamitg

Comment: you have install `ColorInput` ver. 2.0 ? if yes so , use namespace like this `use kartik\widgets\ColorInput;`

Comment: No not version 2 there isn't version 2. I only found version 1 and smth called devmaster. @gamitg

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it ver 1.0.

Comment: No need.. Btw It doesn't see thr kartik class. Because if I try to press ctrl+kartik\widgets\ColorInput it doesnt give a link...

Comment: I think I've missed something.. I've just noticed the download link and downloaded yii2-widget-colorinput-master zip folder. Any idea where should i extract it? @gamitg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89679/discussion-between-gamitg-and-ragheb-alkilany).

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can simply use HTML5 color picker by setting the input type to color.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'color_code')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'type'=>'color']) ?>
```